# Get data value in element from web

Tags: c#, html, linq

I want to get the data from the tags in html on the web, but when usually the website always has many pages, so how can I load all the pages to get the data without pressing the page number

I tried google and heard about skip take linq, but I don't know if it can be useful for my case.
I'm coding on c#. Thanks for helping!

```
int Page = 1;
int RecordsPerPage = 10;
var q = yourQuery.Skip((Page - 1) * RecordsPerPage).Take(RecordsPerPage);
```

Comment: take a look at [LINQ with Skip and Take](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15385905/4977870)